# No Response from Salesforce for Query Operation

Tags: salesforce, mule, mule-studio

I am trying to connect to salesforce for query operation to fetch records for a identifier i recieved from my streaming api. 
here is my flow. The connection is being made with a sandbox url and i have not enabled datasense flag. the reason for not enabling the data sense flag is that the config screen seems to get struck when i enable the datasense flag with mulestudio consuming high cpu processes.

```
<flow name="demoFlow1" doc:name="demoFlow1">
    <sfdc:subscribe-topic config-ref="Salesforce" topic="/AccountsUpdates" doc:name="Salesforce (Streaming)"/>
    <set-payload value="#[payload.Id]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    <sfdc:query config-ref="Salesforce" query="select name from account where id='#[payload]'" doc:name="Salesforce"/>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
</flow>
```

please advise if i am making a mistake.

regards
Santosh

Comment: I added debug to logs and noticed i am getting response to the salesforce query. but the flow does not move beyond the salesforce connector. the echo component is not getting executed.

Comment: Does datasense work with sandbox ?

Comment: 12 hrs and no response yet :(

Comment: another option for getting an answer to your question is the stackexchange site specific to Salesforce at salesforce.stackexchange.com, but I'm not sure if this is a Mule problem or a Salesforce api problem but it never hurts to ask there and get more eyes on the problem you're having.

Comment: "the flow does not move beyond the salesforce connector": what connector? Do you mean the `sfdc:query` message processor? "the echo component is not getting executed": which one? The first one, second one, both?

Comment: I meant the flow would not move beyond the query processor. As i was noticing another issue.I could not configure salesforce connector for sandbox url. test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/29.0/0DFZ000000000f4. The screen would hang on Getting Datasense metadata types. Also mulestudio cpu process would increase up to 50 threads in my task manager. I tried playing with the soap version, changed it to 28 and tried again. this time the getting datasense metadata type wizard closed successfully. the flow worked too.Seems my version 29 wsdl is not being supported yet. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

`<flow name="sfdc_queryFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <sfdc:query config-ref="Salesforce__Basic_authentication" query="SELECT Id, Name, AccountNumber, Type FROM Account where id='0019000001JLSmuAAH'" doc:name="Salesforce"/>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    </flow>`

you can use flow variable in place of id.